# Ionic 4 + FCM: How to fix the compiler error - colorAccent not found?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic4, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am working on an Ionic 4 App. I am trying to customize the color of "default_notification_color", but the compiler throws an error. I have the following in my `config.xml` file:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color" android:resource="@color/orange" />
```

I have created a new file called "colors.xml" and placed it in the following directory in my project root:

```
gf > res > values > colors.xml
```

Here are the contents of colors.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorAccent">#3880ff</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="ivory">#FFFFF0</color>       
    <color name="orange">#FFA500</color>
    <color name="navy">#000080</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

I tried to build the app using the following command:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod
```

But it throws me the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED in 9s
24 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 20 up-to-date
D:\Softwares\wamp\www\gf\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed

  D:\Softwares\wamp\www\gf\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:122: AAPT: error: resource color/orange (aka com.mydomain.myapp:color/orange) not found.

  error: failed processing manifest.
```

How can this be fixed so that the value is read from the `colors.xml` file without any issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. I had to include the following line in `config.xml:`

```
<resource-file src="res/values/colors.xml" target="app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml" />
```

1. What this does is essentially it copies the colors.xml 
   file from the location `res/values` in the project root, to the location `platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/` folder (considering that you are building this for Android)
2. It then looks in the `colors.xml` file for the name "orange" and looks up the corresponding value (i.e. in this case, would be `#FFA500`) and assigns it as the Notification Icon color.

**That's it!** So from now on, whenever a notification is received, its color would be equal to the `orange` color as I indicated in the colors.xml file.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: @Denver - I am getting the same error, however I do have the resource-file line in my config.xml .  What color keys are needed in the `resources/values/colors.xml` file?  I only have `background` and `accent` defined.

Comment: @rolinger Whatever you have, will work fine as long as you use only those variables in the `config.xml` file. So in your case, the values could be: `android:resource="@color/background" or android:resource="@color/accent"`. No anything else other than what I just showed, unless you add them to the colors.xml file first. Makes sense?

Comment: I figured it out, `ic_background` was missing from `colors.xml`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error while installing the plugin **cordova-plugin-firebasex**

Just clean the plugins and the platform was built successfully

```
rm -Rf platforms/android

cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-firebasex

rm -Rf plugins/ node_modules/

npm install

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebasex

ionic cordova build android
```

OR

In case you have a problem,
You can rebuild the platform by modifying the following versions:

**package.json**

```
  "cordova-plugin-firebasex": "^10.2.0-cli", /* VERSION */

  "cordova-plugin-firebasex": { /* OPTIONS */
    "FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED": "true",
    "FIREBASE_PERFORMANCE_COLLECTION_ENABLED": "true",
    "FIREBASE_CRASHLYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED": "true",
    "ANDROID_ICON_ACCENT": "#FF00FFFF",
    "ANDROID_PLAY_SERVICES_AUTH_VERSION": "18.0.0",
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_VERSION": "17.4.3",
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_VERSION": "20.2.1",
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_CONFIG_VERSION": "19.1.4",
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_PERF_VERSION": "19.0.7",
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_AUTH_VERSION": "19.3.1",
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_FIRESTORE_VERSION": "21.4.3",
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_CRASHLYTICS_VERSION": "17.0.1",
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_CRASHLYTICS_NDK_VERSION": "17.0.1",
    "ANDROID_GSON_VERSION": "2.8.6",
    "ANDROID_PLAY_SERVICES_TAGMANAGER_VERSION": "17.0.0",
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_INAPPMESSAGING_VERSION": "19.0.7"
  },

  "@ionic-native/firebase-x": "^5.29.0", /*  */
```